# How to convert a GroupedDataFrame to a DataFrame in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia, plots.jl

I have performed calculations on subsets of a DataFrame by using the `groupby` function:

```
using RDatasets
iris = dataset("datasets", "iris")
describe(iris)
iris_grouped = groupby(iris,:Species)
iris_avg = map(:SepalLength => mean,iris_grouped::GroupedDataFrame)
```

Now I would like to plot the results, but I get an error message for the following plot:

```
@df iris_avg bar(:Species,:SepalLength)
```

> Only tables are supported

What would be the best way to plot the data? My idea would be to create a single DataFrame and go from there. How would I do this, ie how do I convert a GroupedDataFrame to a single DataFrame? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To convert `GroupedDataFrame` into a `DataFrame` just call `DataFrame` on it, e.g.:

```
julia> DataFrame(iris_avg)
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ Species      │ SepalLength_mean │
│     │ Categorical… │ Float64          │
├─────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│ 1   │ setosa       │ 5.006            │
│ 2   │ versicolor   │ 5.936            │
│ 3   │ virginica    │ 6.588            │
```

in your case.

You could also have written:

```
julia> combine(:SepalLength => mean, iris_grouped)
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ Species      │ SepalLength_mean │
│     │ Categorical… │ Float64          │
├─────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│ 1   │ setosa       │ 5.006            │
│ 2   │ versicolor   │ 5.936            │
│ 3   │ virginica    │ 6.588            │
```

on an original `GroupedDataFrame` or

```
julia> by(:SepalLength => mean, iris, :Species)
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ Species      │ SepalLength_mean │
│     │ Categorical… │ Float64          │
├─────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│ 1   │ setosa       │ 5.006            │
│ 2   │ versicolor   │ 5.936            │
│ 3   │ virginica    │ 6.588            │
```

on an original `DataFrame`.

I write the transformation as the first argument here, but typically, you would write it as the last (as then you can pass multiple transformations), e.g.:

```
julia> by(iris, :Species, :SepalLength => mean, :SepalWidth => minimum)
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ Species      │ SepalLength_mean │ SepalWidth_minimum │
│     │ Categorical… │ Float64          │ Float64            │
├─────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│ 1   │ setosa       │ 5.006            │ 2.3                │
│ 2   │ versicolor   │ 5.936            │ 2.0                │
│ 3   │ virginica    │ 6.588            │ 2.2                │
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be better off using the `by` function to get to your `iris_avg` directly. `by` iterates through a `DataFrame`, and then applies the given function to the the results. Often, it's used with a `do` block.

```
julia> by(iris, :Species) do df
           DataFrame(sepal_mean = mean(df.SepalLength))
       end
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ Species      │ sepal_mean │
│     │ Categorical… │ Float64    │
├─────┼──────────────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ setosa       │ 5.006      │
│ 2   │ versicolor   │ 5.936      │
│ 3   │ virginica    │ 6.588      │
```

Or equivalently,

```
julia> by(iris, :Species, SepalLength_mean = :SepalLength => mean)
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ Species      │ SepalLength_mean │
│     │ Categorical… │ Float64          │
├─────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│ 1   │ setosa       │ 5.006            │
│ 2   │ versicolor   │ 5.936            │
│ 3   │ virginica    │ 6.588            │
```

[See here](http://juliadata.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/man/split_apply_combine/) for more details/examples.

Alternatively, you can do it in several steps as you've done, then use `DataFrame` constructor to convert to a proper `DataFrame`:

```
julia> iris_grouped = groupby(iris,:Species);

julia> iris_avg = map(:SepalLength => mean,iris_grouped::GroupedDataFrame);

julia> DataFrame(iris_avg)
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ Species      │ SepalLength_mean │
│     │ Categorical… │ Float64          │
├─────┼──────────────┼──────────────────┤
│ 1   │ setosa       │ 5.006            │
│ 2   │ versicolor   │ 5.936            │
│ 3   │ virginica    │ 6.588            │
```